# Flutter BottomBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation

In the flutter BottomBar the first item is always highlighted. Is there a way to style all items the same way, so that the first item is not highlighted or all highlighted? I define the BottomBar in my ThemeData like :

```
      bottomNavigationBarTheme: BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: getColorFromHex('#9FC039'),
        // elevation: 15,
        selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.60)),
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.60),
        selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 14.0),
        unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 14.0),
      ),
```

Comment: remove the ``withOpacity(.60))`` ?

Comment: The default active index is 0 ,  replace `unselectedItemColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.60),` to `unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,`  as Omi shah mentioned